# How can I affect the execution order of the ExecutorService?

Tags: database, multithreading, executorservice

In the main thread, 2 methods are executed, `viewModel.deleteAllMovies()` and `viewModel.insertListMovies(movies)`:

```
viewModel.deleteAllMovies();
try {
    Thread.sleep(10);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
viewModel.insertListMovies(movies);
```

In the MainViewModel class, these methods are implemented as follows:

```
public void deleteMovie(Movie movie) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.execute(() -> {
        database.movieDao().deleteMovie(movie);
    });
}

public void insertListMovies(List<Movie> movies) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.execute(() -> {
        database.movieDao().insertListMovies(movies);
    });
}
```

When the application is launched, the order of execution of these methods is not controlled, so you have to put the main thread to sleep in order to somehow influence their work.
10 ms is enough for the program to work normally. How can I improve this code so that I don't have to put the main thread to sleep? In my opinion, this is not a good idea. Thanks!